# Navigate to another route within router.events function causes browser to hang up

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am subscribing to the router events in my top navbar component:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized && this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {

         // some other custom if-logic then do this:
         this.router.navigate(['404']);
    }
});
```

When I execute the above code my browser freezes and I have to kill the chrome.exe in the task manager...

Why can I not navigate to another new route while the old route is still navigating?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are under redirect loop mate.
You are calling the router navigate method inside the event block without a specific url in your condition.

Currently your code will execute whenever the url updated so after every redirect it will execute again and again.

To solve this try to add the route as well with condition so it will not execute for every url it'll be something like

```
 this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  let url = this.router.url;
  if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized && this.authService.isLoggedIn() && url !== "/404") {

     // some other custom if-logic then do this:
     this.router.navigate(['404']);
   }
  });
```

Replace url logic with your own but you have to restrict your code to execute on specific pages instead of all in upper example it wont execute on 404 route.

Comment: Thanks your hint is true. I will not fix that error. That problem of some other problems is just due to a requirement which I set myself but I choosed to change my init ui drastically, thus such worksaround are not needed anymore :-)